# Prove that $|a-b| \leq |a-c| + |c-d| + |d-b| $ $ \forall a,b,c,d $

Tags: real-analysis

I know this is based on the triangle inequality that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$ which I can prove using the fact that $(a+b)^{2} \leq (|a| + |b|)^{2}$. That is about how far I've gotten with this so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $|x+y+z|\leq |x|+|y|+|z|$. Find suitable $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

note that 
$$
|a-b|=|a-c+c-d+d-b|
$$
and use two times the triangle inequality.